# MySQL search problem to find lowercase and uppercase letters at the sametime

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where users enters there username in both lower case(eg: arup) and uppercase(eg: Arup) or both (eg: aRuP).

But my problem is now that if I search database to show member username like %Arup, mysql returns empty result if not founds exactly.

```
 id    |   username   |   name    |   sex
  1         arUp         Arup Sarma   Male

<?php
$q=strip_tags($_POST['user']); /// eg. Arup
$qry=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT id,name,sex FROM membertable WHERE username='%$q'"));
echo $qry['0']."<br>".$qry['1']."<br>".$qry['2'];
?>
/// Now above sql query will return zero result as there is no username in the form of arUp.
```

How to make SQL query Case-insensitive ?
anyone help please...

Comment: while not a duplicate, this question provides useful related answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558967/how-to-check-for-uppercase-letters-in-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,202839,202856#msg-202856) could help to understand your problem...
Anyway you could solve your problem with this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE LOWER(username) LIKE '%arup'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `UPPER` on both sides of the comparison:

```
SELECT id,name,sex FROM membertable WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%$q')
```

The "right way", according to the official manual, is [choosing a case-insensitive collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html), which might be faster but is also more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

based on this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

i'd try this:

```
where username COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = '%$q'
```